# Is it possible to use Box with no_std?

Tags: rust

I'd like to use `Box` in a crate with `no_std`. Is this possible? My simple attempts so far have not worked.

This compiles (but uses the standard library):

```
fn main() {
    let _: Box<[u8]> = Box::new([0; 10]);
}
```

This does not:

```
#![no_std]

fn main() {
    let _: Box<[u8]> = Box::new([0; 10]);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Bno_std%5D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_%3A%20Box%3C%5Bu8%5D%3E%20%3D%20Box%3A%3Anew(%5B0%3B%2010%5D)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=nightly&backtrace=0))

However, looking through the Rust source code, I see `Box` is defined in liballoc with the warning

> This library, like libcore, is not intended for general usage, but rather as a building block of other libraries. The types and interfaces in this library are reexported through the standard library, and should not be used through this library.

Since `Box` doesn't depend on std but is only reexported for it, it seems like I only need to figure out the right way to import it into my code. (Despite this seeming to be not recommended.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to import [the `alloc` crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/index.html):

```
#![no_std]

extern crate alloc;

use alloc::boxed::Box;

fn main() {
    let _: Box<[u8]> = Box::new([0; 10]);
}
```

The `alloc` crate is compiler-provided (just as `std` in non-`no_std` environments), so you don't need to pull it from crates.io or specify it in `Cargo.toml`. The crate is stable since Rust 1.36 ([stabilization PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/59675)).

Note that this compiles as a lib, but not as binary because of missing `lang_items`. Compiling a `no_std` binary unfortunately still requires Rust nightly.

Comment: No, there isn't. But if you want dynamic allocation (not `Box`), you can use `libc::malloc`.

Comment: @AndrewStraw *forever off stable* — the point of features is that they exist while being proven, then are turned on for everyone. AFAIK, there's **nothing** in Rust that exists for the sole purpose of never being available in a stable release. It's just a matter of time and usefulness.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit, it seems Box<> should not be in the basic language definition because it assumes a heap. But a heap may not be available on all platforms.

Comment: You are right @AndrewStraw, this is the exact reason.

Comment: Those of us writing code for microprocessors are quite happy about that decision by the Rust team.